# Pythonic way of modifiying a string with a temporary list

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I have a string that is several thousand chars long and contains about 100 `\n`, separating it out when printed. I am deleting any lines that contain certain substrings, and certain individual chars.

This part is already completed, but I'm curious as to what the most *pythonic* way of doing this is, and, assuming the method i've chosen is sound, if there is an appropriate naming convention for the temporary list.

```
active_config = active_config.split('\n')

for i, elem in enumerate(active_config):
    # Delete entire line based off match
    if "cmdStatus=" in elem or "<?xml" in elem:
        active_config.remove(elem)

    #Delete individual char based off match
    elem = elem.replace("\r","")
# Delete last line if it is '*'
if active_config[-1] == "*":
    del active_config[-1]

active_config = '\n'.join(active_config)
```

I have chosen to overwrite the string `active_config` as a list, and then overwrite that as a string again after deleting certain elements is complete.

Since the list is only ever used to remove a few lines and individual characters, and never used elsewhere, is there a special convention for what I should call it? Perhaps call it `active_config_list` or `temp_active_config` or even just `temp`.

Comment: Modifying a list while you're iterating over it is a bad idea, as it tends to throw off your position in the list. Also, `remove` is a really slow way to remove elements from a list, since it has to locate the element again. Build a new list instead of deleting from an existing one.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't test _every_ line in the list to see if it's the last line, just do that stuff outside the loop. And you have your `.join` call backwards. It should be `separator_string.join(list_of_strings)`

Comment: @PM2Ring, you were right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pythonic solution for this type of problem using [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
active_config = """this is an
example which contains
words like
cmdStatus=
cmdStatus2
or other
weird <?lxml
tags
"""

lines = active_config.splitlines()
tokens = ["cmdStatus=", "<?lxml"]
print '\n'.join(filter(lambda x: not any(w in x for w in tokens), lines))
```

Comment: Ah yes, I know of lambda list comprehension, but often forget to use it!

And to answer the other part of this question. Is a temporary var like `lines` preferable to my method of reusing the same var name and writing it over twice?

Comment: @BrianC I've edited my code, instead of using split('\n') I'd suggest you using splitlines() instead. About keeping or reusing the var name, well, i'd prefer keeping my original input for other usage. Unless you're concerned with memory issues, which won't be likely :)

Comment: I do use the original input var elsewhere, as I said, I basically do `a = "some\nstuff" ` then `a = a.split("\n")` , modify elements of a, then `a = "\n".join(a)`. So there is no convention here, just preference?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of list comprehensions will do it too:

```
active_config = active_config.split('\n')

temp_list = [z for z in active_config if "cmdStatus=" in z or "<?xml" in z]

if temp_list[-1] == "*":
    temp_list = "\n".join([x.replace("\r", "") for x in temp_list[:-1]])

#Do whatever you need to do with temp_list here
```